# How to use FFSampledSP. An example is desired

Tags: java, audio, flac

There is an library called FFSampledSP on GitHub.

I want to ask if anyone have an small example how I can use FFSampledSP to play an FLAC-file.

Also, I can't figure out how I shall use these file for the test.
ffsampledsp.jar
libffsampledsp.jnilib

I'm using Java 7 on Windows8 and Eclipse as IDE.

Thanks in advance!

Br

Mark Stone

Comment: According to their documentation it is an SPI implementation. You just install it and `javax.sound` will play the newly supported formats normally. (That is how SPI works.)

Comment: Ok, thanks !, now I understand. Now it's just about adding JNI lib and the JAR file in the right place. So no programming examples needed ... But maybe a place the files right example. Looking at it tomorrow. Thanks for the quick reply.